# "gulp serve" is returning this error "Cannot GET /temp/workbench.html" when open "https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html"

Tags: development, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp

I want to create an SPFx web part, so i run these commands:-

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
gulp serve
```

then when i try to run `gulp serve`, i got this error:-

```
Cannot GET /temp/workbench.html
```

[image]

here is the list of components modules that i have:-

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm ls -g --depth=0
C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
`-- yo@4.3.0
```

&

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 14.18.1 (x64) and npm.

C:\Windows\System32>npm list --global
C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0
| +-- @microsoft/spfx-heft-plugins@1.13.0
| | +-- @azure/storage-blob@12.4.1
| | | +-- @azure/abort-controller@1.0.4
| | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | +-- @azure/core-http@1.2.6
| | | | +-- @azure/abort-controller@1.0.4 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill@1.0.0
| | | | +-- @azure/core-auth@1.3.2
| | | | | +-- @azure/abort-controller@1.0.4 deduped
| | | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-tracing@1.0.0-preview.11
| | | | | +-- @opencensus/web-types@0.0.7 deduped
| | | | | +-- @opentelemetry/api@1.0.0-rc.0
| | | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/logger@1.0.3 deduped
| | | | +-- @types/node-fetch@2.5.12
| | | | | +-- @types/node@16.11.7
| | | | | `-- form-data@3.0.1 deduped
| | | | +-- @types/tunnel@0.0.1
| | | | | `-- @types/node@16.11.7 deduped
| | | | +-- form-data@3.0.1
| | | | | +-- asynckit@0.4.0
| | | | | +-- combined-stream@1.0.8 deduped
| | | | | `-- mime-types@2.1.34 deduped
| | | | +-- node-fetch@2.6.6 deduped
| | | | +-- process@0.11.10
| | | | +-- tough-cookie@4.0.0
| | | | | +-- psl@1.8.0
| | | | | +-- punycode@2.1.1
| | | | | `-- universalify@0.1.2 deduped
| | | | +-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | | +-- tunnel@0.0.6
| | | | +-- uuid@8.3.2
| | | | `-- xml2js@0.4.23
| | | |   +-- sax@1.2.4 deduped
| | | |   `-- xmlbuilder@11.0.1
| | | +-- @azure/core-lro@1.0.5
| | | | +-- @azure/abort-controller@1.0.4 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-http@1.2.6 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-tracing@1.0.0-preview.11
| | | | | +-- @opencensus/web-types@0.0.7 deduped
| | | | | +-- @opentelemetry/api@1.0.0-rc.0
| | | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | | +-- events@3.3.0 deduped
| | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | +-- @azure/core-paging@1.2.0
| | | | +-- @azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill@1.0.0 deduped
| | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | +-- @azure/core-tracing@1.0.0-preview.9
| | | | +-- @opencensus/web-types@0.0.7
| | | | +-- @opentelemetry/api@0.10.2 deduped
| | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | +-- @azure/logger@1.0.3
| | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | +-- @opentelemetry/api@0.10.2
| | | | `-- @opentelemetry/context-base@0.10.2
| | | +-- events@3.3.0
| | | `-- tslib@2.3.1
| | +-- @microsoft/hashed-folder-copy-plugin@1.13.0
| | | +-- @rushstack/node-core-library@3.40.0 deduped
| | | `-- glob@7.0.6 deduped
| | +-- @microsoft/loader-load-themed-styles@1.9.89
| | | +-- @microsoft/load-themed-styles@1.10.208
| | | `-- loader-utils@1.1.0
| | |   +-- big.js@3.2.0
| | |   +-- emojis-list@2.1.0
| | |   `-- json5@0.5.1
| | +-- @microsoft/rush-lib@5.52.0
| | | +-- @azure/identity@1.0.3
| | | | +-- @azure/core-http@1.2.6 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-tracing@1.0.0-preview.7
| | | | | +-- @opencensus/web-types@0.0.7 deduped
| | | | | +-- @opentelemetry/types@0.2.0 deduped
| | | | | `-- tslib@1.14.1 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/logger@1.0.3 deduped
| | | | +-- @opentelemetry/types@0.2.0
| | | | +-- events@3.3.0 deduped
| | | | +-- jws@3.2.2
| | | | | +-- jwa@1.4.1
| | | | | | +-- buffer-equal-constant-time@1.0.1
| | | | | | +-- ecdsa-sig-formatter@1.0.11
| | | | | | | `-- safe-buffer@5.2.1 deduped
| | | | | | `-- safe-buffer@5.2.1 deduped
| | | | | `-- safe-buffer@5.2.1 deduped
| | | | +-- msal@1.4.15
| | | | | `-- tslib@1.14.1
| | | | +-- qs@6.10.1
| | | | | `-- side-channel@1.0.4
| | | | |   +-- call-bind@1.0.2
| | | | |   | +-- function-bind@1.1.1 deduped
| | | | |   | `-- get-intrinsic@1.1.1 deduped
| | | | |   +-- get-intrinsic@1.1.1
| | | | |   | +-- function-bind@1.1.1 deduped
| | | | |   | +-- has@1.0.3 deduped
| | | | |   | `-- has-symbols@1.0.2
| | | | |   `-- object-inspect@1.11.0
| | | | +-- tslib@1.14.1
| | | | `-- uuid@3.4.0
| | | +-- @azure/storage-blob@12.3.0
| | | | +-- @azure/abort-controller@1.0.4 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-http@1.2.6 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-lro@1.0.5 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-paging@1.2.0 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/core-tracing@1.0.0-preview.9 deduped
| | | | +-- @azure/logger@1.0.3 deduped
| | | | +-- @opentelemetry/api@0.10.2 deduped
| | | | +-- events@3.3.0 deduped
| | | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | | +-- @pnpm/link-bins@5.3.25
| | | | +-- @pnpm/error@1.4.0
| | | | +-- @pnpm/package-bins@4.1.0
| | | | | +-- @pnpm/types@6.4.0 deduped
| | | | | +-- fast-glob@3.2.7 deduped
| | | | | `-- is-subdir@1.2.0 deduped
| | | | +-- @pnpm/read-modules-dir@2.0.3
| | | | | `-- mz@2.7.0 deduped
| | | | +-- @pnpm/read-package-json@4.0.0
| | | | | +-- @pnpm/error@1.4.0 deduped
| | | | | +-- @pnpm/types@6.4.0 deduped
| | | | | +-- load-json-file@6.2.0
| | | | | | +-- graceful-fs@4.2.8 deduped
| | | | | | +-- parse-json@5.2.0 deduped
| | | | | | +-- strip-bom@4.0.0 deduped
| | | | | | `-- type-fest@0.6.0
| | | | | `-- normalize-package-data@3.0.3
| | | | |   +-- hosted-git-info@4.0.2
| | | | |   | `-- lru-cache@6.0.0 deduped
| | | | |   +-- is-core-module@2.8.0
| | | | |   | `-- has@1.0.3 deduped
| | | | |   +-- semver@7.3.5 deduped
| | | | |   `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4 deduped
| | | | +-- @pnpm/read-project-manifest@1.1.7
| | | | | +-- @pnpm/error@1.4.0 deduped
| | | | | +-- @pnpm/types@6.4.0 deduped
| | | | | +-- @pnpm/write-project-manifest@1.1.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[From SPFx 1.13 release notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.13)**

> To configure the browser launch correctly, update the initialPage property within the ./config/serve.json to point to your SharePoint Online tenant. For example: https://TENANT_NAME.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx.

Not performing this configuration task will result in an error the first time gulp serve runs.

Comment: ok thanks for the helpful reply

Comment: This confused me for a while as I didn't know what `contoso` was supposed to represent. It wasn't clear I should literally use my SharePoint tenant URL generated when i signed up for a trial tenant, eg a1b2c3.sharepoint.com.